# Tailwind transition :after

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I've got this html

```
<ul class="flex gap-3"><li class="after:content-[''] after:block after:w-0 after:h-2 after:bg-black hover:after:w-full transition duration-1000 ease-in-out"><a href="/" class="text-lg font-bold text-black uppercase" > home </a></li></ul>
```

on hover I'd like to apply transition for a nice animation
but there is no animation
Could you help me, please?

https://play.tailwindcss.com/1N3yf48DL1

Comment: You can't call pseudos as classes in html.

Comment: @NathanielFlick actually you can in TailwindCSS.

Comment: Ah whoops that's an attribute, not a pseudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of changes are needed:

1. The `transition` class in TailwindCSS transitions: color, background-color, border-color, text-decoration-color, fill, stroke, opacity, box-shadow, transform, filter, backdrop-filter.  It doesn't transition width.  So you can change that to either be `transition-all` or `transition-[width]`.
2. You need to set the transition property classes on the after element so change them to `after:transition-all after:duration-1000 after:ease-in-out`

#### Working snippet:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<ul class="flex gap-3">
  <li class="after:content-[''] after:block after:w-0 after:h-2 after:bg-black hover:after:w-full after:transition-all after:duration-1000 after:ease-in-out">
    <a href="/" class="text-lg font-bold text-black uppercase" > home </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to this Tailwind documentation: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states

Anyway, I tried modifying your code into this:

```
<ul class="flex gap-3"><li class="after:content-[''] after:block after:w-0 after:h-2 after:bg-black hover:after:w-full hover:after:transition-all transition duration-1000 ease-in-out"><a href="/" class="text-lg font-bold text-black uppercase" > home </a></li></ul>
```

So you could further stack pseudo classes in TailwindCSS like `hover:after:some-tw-class`

I hope this helps.